# How to select Birthday(Month) drop down in the gmail registration page by Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

This is my code but its not select the value

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default");
Thread.sleep(3000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select']")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);

List<WebElement>menu=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='goog-menuitem-content']"));
Thread.sleep(3000);

for(int i=0;i<menu.size();i++){

    WebElement element=menu.get(i);

    String innerhtml=element.getAttribute("innerHTML");


    if(innerhtml.contentEquals("April"))
    {
     element.click();
     break;          
     }

    System.out.println("value of dropdown "+innerhtml);
}
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following code:

```
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='BirthMonth']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='goog-menuitem-content' and text()='April']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you did a setProperty for the gecko driver, in case, you're using Firefox browser.

Try this code after that point:

```
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?hl=en");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div[1]")).click();
    //Thread.sleep(3000);
    List<WebElement> months= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='option']"));  //xpath of the list as a whole
    System.out.println(months.size());
    for(WebElement obj : months)
    {
        System.out.println(obj.getText());
        if(obj.getText().contains("August"))
        {
            obj.click();
        }

    }
```

Hope, this works for you.